# Add tableView to a ScrolledWindow in gtkmm 2 for c++

Tags: c++, tableview, gtkmm

Are there any simple ways (Classes) in gtkmm 2  to create a tableview for a Gui.

I would like to add a table to my ScrolledWindow object, instead of (what I have right now) a textView.

```
 Gtk::ScrolledWindow m_ScrolledWindow;
 m_ScrolledWindow.add(textView);
```

That is - instead of the textView I would like to add some kind of tableview - according to the image

[image]

Comment: In gtkmm the table widget is called a `treeview`: https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/2.24/gtkmm-tutorial.html#chapter-treeview